# I need help for translate C# to Vb (with EventHandlers)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, eventhandler

i have my code :

```
client.NotifyClientEnterView += (source, notification) => Console.WriteLine("ClientEnterView {0}: {1}", notification.Clid, notification.ClientNickname);
```

And i want to translate it in VB.NET
(it's not working with a translator when i enter it)

I tryed AddHandler method, but it's not working (Beceause it's a eventhandler, not a event, like this : `Addhandler client.NotifyClientEnterView, adressof <mysub>`)

I need to translate that for execute a sub when a client enter in the channel (in teamspeak)

My library : https://github.com/Spksh/TentacleSoftware.TeamSpeakQuery

Nota : client.NotifyClientEnterView as EVENTHANDLER, not a EVENT.

I hope you understand my problem, and thank for you help.

Comment: Can you explain what this does currently? Also we *do not translate code* we help with actual programming issues. There are many provider's that can do this. If it is not working, explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I tryed AddHandler method, but it's not working (Beceause it's a eventhandler, not a event, like this : Addhandler client.NotifyClientEnterView, adressof <mysub>)

Comment: I suggest you add to this question. Code you have tried. What you need to achieve. Take a stab at it in VB.NET and post error, even if its a compile error. A start http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5041/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-VB-NET

Comment: Thank for your link, but i already know what is a event in VB. (I written more information, refresh the page)

Answer (score 0):

'AddressOf' is not used for the case of wiring a lambda to an event.
So, approach the problem in 2 steps:
1. Use 'AddHandler' (as you already know)
2. Replace the C# lambda with a VB lambda using the following pattern replacement: '(..) => ..code..' -> 'Sub(..) ..code..'.
e.g.,

```
AddHandler client.NotifyClientEnterView, Sub(source, notification) Console.WriteLine("ClientEnterView {0}: {1}", notification.Clid, notification.ClientNickname)
```

Comment: I added the conversion - but please try to understand the process.

Comment: @SimonEtlafamille: You don't need 'End Sub' for an expression lambda.

Comment: @SimonEtlafamille: I don't see 'NotifyTextMessage' anywhere in your code.

Comment: Someone for my problem ?